# Синхронизация доступа к коллекции

Tags: многопоточность, java

Здравствуйте! Имеется коллекция и n потоков, в обычном режиме потоки читают данные из коллекции (как я понимаю в такой ситуации синхронизация не нужна) и давольно редко возникают случаи когда определенные потоки модифицируют коллекцию. Какими методами наиболее эффективно можно организовать синхронизацию?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Java есть такая замечательная штука как `SynchronizedCollection`. Как правило коллекции в Java несинхронизированные (чтобы увеличить их скорость работы).

В многопоточной среде, когда требуется скажем, синхронизированный список, то можно использовать конструкцию:

```
List<String> syncList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
```

И не надо никаких `java.util.concurrent` (впрочем это не отменяет необходимости знания пакета `concurrent`)

Comment: Совет не совсем про эффективное решение :)

Answer (score 3):

Если организовать синхронизацию - не учебное задание, то лучше всего посмотреть на пакет [`java.util.concurrent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html). Там есть и потокобезопасные коллекции, и классы вроде `ReentrantLock` или `Semaphore`, позволяющие ограничить число потоков, одновременно выполняющих определённый код. Использование готовых решений позволит не наступить на множество граблей, которые поджидают любого, кто пишет многопоточный код.

[Обзор java.util.concurrent](http://habrahabr.ru/company/luxoft/blog/157273/)

Answer (score 1):

Для вашей задачи подойдет [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) или [ConcurrentLinkedDeque](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedDeque.html) (если вы хотите работать со связным списком, только интерфейс другой).

Если у вас имеются ограничения по памяти, то используйте синхронизацию к обычному списку с помощью [ReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html), который позволяет нескольким потокам выполнять чтение и только одному потоку выполнять эксклюзивную запись.